# Who implements the OS interfacing in java?

Tags: java, interface, java-native-interface, standards, standard-library

My question is regarding mostly the standard, but input on how specific implementations deal with the issue is welcome too. So without further redo, my question is;

- Who is responsible for the operating system interfacing in Java?

  - The Java Virtual Machine?
  - or the Java Class Library?

Also how is this usually implemented, through Java Native Interface?

Example; I'm reading a file, using java.io.FileReader. When invoking `read` on this object the JVM will obviously call this function, in the correct class file, in the JCL, however will this code in the end rely on the JVM for calling, for instance the posix `read` function? - or will the class file do this itself, through the use of JNI? (assuming a `read` has to be done, that is the file isn't already in cache/memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping some real professional would answer this, preferrably someone who has actually worked on a JVM/JDK. Since so far, none of them seem to be online (or have seen your question, for that matter), I will have a go at explaining this.

The Java Class Library classes (found in the `rt.jar` file of your JRE/JDK) are in fact pure java. They do contain a lot of JNI calls, though. If you look at the source of `FileInputStream` for example, you will find stuff like this:

```
private native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len)
    throws IOException;

public int read(byte b[])
    throws IOException
{
    return readBytes(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

So your guess was correct: the JCL does make extensive use of JNI. But who provides those native implementations? Simple: The JVM. And that is how the pieces fit together.

Comment: So really, the JVM just provides the generic JNI functionality, which is used by the JCL to implement all system depended operations, by calling C code?

Comment: Also does this mean, that one could implement a JVM and simply borrow the JCL from another JVM (for the same platform)?

Comment: First question: Yes indeed. Second question: In theory, this should work, yes. At least, I cannot see why it should not work.

Comment: Alright, I'll accept your answer and do a little research into the field of JNI then.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your core question, the JVM is responsible for the OS shell integration. The Java Class Library (API) is a set of functionality that uses the JVM, that's why it is also called an API.

Regarding the JNI integration, the JVM is handling these calls. At your class level, you have to declare the code that has a native implementation.

Let's take for instance the System.arraycopy() method. This method has a native implementation. The System class defines the signature of the method and the JVM is responsible for translating the call from the System.arraycopy() method to the native underlaying implementation. If you download the OpenJDK sources from [here](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/), you can check this .cpp file *hotspot\src\share\vm\oops\objArrayKlass.cpp*:

```
void objArrayKlass::copy_array(arrayOop s, int src_pos, arrayOop d,
                       int dst_pos, int length, TRAPS) { ... }
```